# db_select with groupBy(CAST(column as DATE))

Tags: 7, database

I am looking to achieve `GROUP BY CAST(date_time AS DATE)` in a `db_select` function in Drupal 7 but with no idea how.

The function up until now is:

```
 foreach ($distinct_users as $user){
    $day_record = db_select('mytable', 'p')
      ->condition('p.processed', 0, '=')
      ->condition('p.first_name', $user['first_name'], '=')
      ->condition('p.last_name', $user['last_name'], '=')
```

and I need to group the results by day which is in `Y-m-d H:i:s` in my table column.

Please advise.

Comment: Try with `$connection = Database::getConnection();
$sth = $connection->select('mytable', 'p');
$sth->condition('p.processed', 0, '=')
  ->condition('p.first_name', $user['first_name'], '=')
  ->condition('p.last_name', $user['last_name'], '=');

$sth->addExpression('CAST(p.date_time)', 'cast');
$sth->groupBy('p.date_time');
// Execute the statement
$data = $sth->execute();
// Get all the results
$results = $data->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` see here https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2015-03-27/count-with-group-by-clause-in-db

Comment: Well, pretty close to be honest.
Now I get an array. Seems to return the right number of elements but it only returns the casted date.

Something like $results{array}
0 = {StdClass}[1]
cast = "2019-11-01"

And so on.

Comment: Can you update your question with some examples of the rows in the database table, and what the array returned by a db_select() function on those rows should look like? If you know the SQL statement that gives the results you are looking for, then including that may be helpful as well.

Comment: I found a workaround, I am currently grouping them in PHP instead of getting them grouped from SQL.
What I was looking for was to get this into Drupal 7. 
SELECT * FROM mytable AS p WHERE p.processed = 0 AND p.first_name = my users's first name AND p.last_name = my user's last name GROUP BY CAST(p.date_time AS DATE).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked for me was to group results via php.